# Mysql sum column value and update other filed with total

Tags: mysql

I have the following table..

```
Id  Amount Balance total
1     10     15     A
2     10     12     A
3      4     11     A
4     10      6     A
```

What I need, calculate the total and update the value in the same table (Replace A). This is the result I want...

```
Id  Amount Balance total
1     10     15     25
2     10     12     22
3      4     11     15
4     10      6     16
```

How do I achieve that in mysql query?

Comment: Do you want to *update* the table or make view or query returns the specified result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update table set total = Amount + Balance;`

Comment: That is such Brilliant and Very Easy Answer to Grasp and Work on it. Thanks Grissom.